# Joomla: How to style the main articles in an own template

Tags: templates, joomla2.5

i'm writing some new Joomla Template for a homepage and now i want to style the main-articles on the front page in some special way. Can anybody tell me how to do this ? Do I need some CSS for this or anything else? Same for the category-list. In advance, thanks for your help. At the moment it looks like this (http://kirschroth.de/) but it should look something like this (www.vflprimstal.de).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the appropriate css to your template file. As I could see it's located at: `/templates/kirschroth/css/template.css`

A quick tip if you want to have different style in each page, you could add a class to menu item `Menus -> *Your_Menu -> *Menu_Item_Name -> Page Display -> Page Class` and call it in your css file for separate styling.

Good Luck!

Comment: And for those grey "fields" around the articles, any idea for that?

Comment: please try: #middle { background: #cccccc; }
#middle div.items-leading, #middle div.items-row div.item { padding: 10px; background: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #414141; }